# Is there any guarantee with `std::regex_search` when there are multiples match possibilities

Tags: c++, regex

I was wondering if there is any guarantee about what does `std::regex_search` match when there are multiples match possibilities.

For example consider this simple regex that look for two positive integers: `([0-9]+).+([0-9]+)`.

If I search in this string `<foo>123</foo><bar>456</bar>789<foobar>` the two numbers matched could be:

- 123 and 456
- 456 and 789
- 123 and 789
- 2 and 56
- 4 and 5
- a lot of other possibilities...

---

To get a guarrantee that only full numbers are matched I can change the regex to `>([0-9]+)<.+>([0-9]+)<` and now the two numbers matched could be:

- 123 and 456
- 456 and 789
- 123 and 789

Is there any guarantee about which of theses 3 possibilities will be returned by `std::regex_search` ?

If not, how to get the guarantee to get for example the first and shortest match (123 and 456) ?

---

```cpp
    std::string str = "<foo>123</foo><bar>456</bar>789<foobar>";

    std::regex expr(">([0-9]+)<.+>([0-9]+)<");
    std::smatch match;

    if(!std::regex_search(str, match, expr))
        puts("Not found");

    printf("First number: %s\nSecond one: %s\n", match.str(1).c_str(), match.str(2).c_str());
```

The output I get is `123` and `789` but I expect `123` and `456`.

Comment: You need to make your `+` quantifier lazy [`>([0-9]+)<.+?>([0-9]+)<`](https://regex101.com/r/09PaZC/1/)

Comment: IIRC regular expressions are generally greedy, and try to match as long sub-string as possible. That means `"<.+>"` will match all of `"</foo><bar>456</bar>"`.

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, why do you use `puts` and `printf` to print the output? Why not `std::cout`?

Comment: @CodeManiac that's what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just an habit from C